# Shared data between local projects

Tags: python, dataframe

I have `DataFrame` that weighs more than 10GB and his data changing once at day.

There is many different local projects that need the entire data of this `DataFrame`.

I wondering if I can create a local application that will load the `DataFrame` into the memory, and all the rest projects that will need the data will call a function to get instance of the `DataFrame` instead of load the data...

How could I do it?

Comment: Looks like you need a sql server. Try Postgres it is free.

Comment: Reading from SQL will take the same effect, I want to pass an instance of object, that should be super fast not like reading 10GB from some SQL service... no?